# How to capture HTTP Put Requests using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, http-put

I am trying to create an HTTP PUT request. I'm able to send successfully but how do I capture the data being send over ?

When using HTTP Post, the URL being called is triggered, I can capture is using Request.Form, but for HTTP PUT, there seems to be no trigger at all.

This is a sample code on how do I initiate :

HTTP PUT:

```
var url = "http://localhost:81/index.aspx";<br>
  var client = new HttpClient();
<br>var content = new StringContent("<xml><message>TEST PUT</message></xml>");
         <br>   var response = client.PutAsync(url, content).Result;
```

What do I do to capture the data in my index.aspx ?

**UPDATE**
I created an HTTP handler to accept HTTP requests. Calling it http://localhost/RestService/employee

Then I use Fiddler to test POST,GET,DELETE and PUT. Three of the method works and invoke my service. But the PUT method, only returns http 200 from fiddler without invoking my service. What is so special with PUT that I need to configure?

This is my code from RestService

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
   LogMessage("Service invoked");
   LogMessage("Method used:" + context.Request.HttpMethod);
}
```

Thanks for your future response.

Comment: If you are trying to use different method type, why don't you use webapi or mvc, thay have builtin support in this mehod types

Comment: Unfortunately, the existing web application is still using web forms and its not an option for me to change as there will be affected structure.

Comment: if your backend dosent support put , then use something else from the client

Comment: I manage to make my server allow PUT requests, its just how I capture the data once the requests has been send over.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to receive the data that is returned by the webs server, right? In that case, why not use:

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
    var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```